# scala event swing :: chicken or egg

Tags: swing, events, scala

how can I handle a situation, where a filed listens to a buttons that is not declared yet?

```
  val detail = new BoxPanel(Orientation.Vertical){
    listenTo(button)
  }
  val seznam = new BoxPanel(Orientation.Vertical){
    val button = new Button("But"){
      reactions += {
        case ButtonClicked(_) =>
          detail.contents.clear
          detail.contents += new Label("Anystring")
    }
  }
```

I can't declare `seznam` first either, because it reference the field `detail`. So how can I write this?

Comment: Try making one or both fields a `lazy val`.

Comment: +1 for an interesting title :-)

Comment: i edited every val : `%s/val/lazy val/g` and I still get `not found` error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`listenTo` is a public method.  The easiest thing to do, therefore, is to create them as you've shown above, but add `detail.listenTo(button)` after you've created the button:

```
val detail = new BoxPanel(Orientation.Vertical){ }
val seznam:BoxPanel = new BoxPanel(Orientation.Vertical){
  val button = new Button("But"){
    reactions += {
      case ButtonClicked(_) =>
        detail.contents.clear
        detail.contents += new Label("Anystring")
    }
  }
  detail.listenTo(button)
}
```